# Getting EOFError along with exceptions when using ftplib

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib, eoferror, ftputil

I'm looking into using ftplib (and possibly [ftputil](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ftputil/2.4.1)) for doing some automated FTP file syncing. I have a couple of servers to test this against at the moment, but, whilst I'm having a successful conversation with both servers, I get EOFError-s with each error reply. For example: if I try to log in with an incorrect user/pass, I will get the 530 response with everything... but I also get an EOFError; if I login with a correct user/pass or try to dir() after doing so etc., I get no EOFError.

It seems to only appear with error messages. I strongly suspect this may be caused by the servers rather than python: I've not found any mention of this issue elsewhere. I, however, have very little control over the server setup.

I'm asking for ideas:

- Do you know what could be causing the error in the first place?
- If it's server-side, could you be more specific? I won't know if I'll be able to do anything about it until I know what it is...
- How do you think I should handle this? I guess I could add an `except EOFError: pass` before each time I handle an exception, but if you have better/neater ideas I would love to hear them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The servers are sending `EOF` to tell you that they've terminated the connection.

You should treat this no differently than any other disconnection event, except that obviously you need to handle it with `except EOFError`.

See the source, from http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/ftplib.py?view=markup

```
# Internal: return one line from the server, stripping CRLF.
# Raise EOFError if the connection is closed
182     def getline(self):
183         line = self.file.readline()
184         if self.debugging > 1:
185             print '*get*', self.sanitize(line)
186         if not line: raise EOFError
187         if line[-2:] == CRLF: line = line[:-2]
188         elif line[-1:] in CRLF: line = line[:-1]
189         return line
```

EOFError is only raised when `readline()` on the connection returns a blank line, which the comment indicates is a disconnection event.

Edit in re your comment:

The server doesn't send an empty line. `readline()` returns everything up to the next `\n` or `\r` or `\r\n` or all of the abouve depending on how it's configured. In this case, **there is nothing to read** because the end of the file has been reached. This causes `readline()` to **return** a blank line, it doesn't mean a blank line has been read. If a blank line had been read, `readline()` would return the character that ended the line (`\n` or `\r` or `\n\r`).

If you don't get the exception when using FTPUtil, that is because it handles it internally.

Comment: I don't think they are... I can log in, get a directory listing, try to create a directory I don't have permissions to create (and get and `EOFerror` along with the `error_perm`), then `dir()` _again_ on the same connection object successfully. Shouldn't I not be able to do the latter (or at least need to re-log-in) if it had closed the connection?

Comment: I think there may be two levels of connection -- each request and response is essentially one connection, while the control channel is essentially another connection. This `EOF` happens after every command (I think), but it only bubbles up to you when the command was an error.

Comment: I suppose so, but I still don't really know why the sever sends an empty line with exceptions... On top of that, [`ftputil`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ftputil/2.4.1) gives me only the relevant exception, even though it appears to use `ftplib`...

Comment: Thanks for explaining it step-by-step :) I still think it's somewhat weird behaviour, but it's probably some unfortunate synergy between this library and the server I'm connecting to... Thanks again.